# React Native : flexGrow , flexBasis, flexShrink not recognized as valid properties

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

**How I'm running it:**

I'm running an Android Studios virtual device and building and bundling with `react-native run-android` `react-native start` respectively.

**Problem:**

It throws the error that `flexGrow` is not a valid style property. It gives a list of all the valid properties and  `flexGrow` , `flexBasis`, `flexShrink` are not in the list with the other flex properties.

I tried to use `flexGrow` like so:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    flexGrow: 0,
    flexShrink: 0, 
    flexBasis: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'hotpink'
  }
});
```

**Question:**

What is the most likely cause that `flexGrow` , `flexBasis`, `flexShrink` are not being recognized as valid props?

Answer (score 1):

I had react-native version 0.33.0 but those properties did not become a part of the react-native style properties until Sept 2016(version 0.34.1). I updated to that version and the problem was fixed! Thanks to all who reviewed this issue!

Answer (score 0):

The "most likely cause" is, unfortunately, that these properties are not supported by React Native. React Native's flexbox is a very stripped down version. Try looking [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html) for more information on what a valid flexbox layout looks like in React Native.

Comment: Thanks joseph for looking into the problem! They just recently added it so I had to update the version I was using. Wish the blog better covered what is added with each update. :)